# How to approach general solutions to functional equations of multiple variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I understand the concept of a function, broadly speaking, but when it comes down to solving general functional equations, I sometimes find it difficult to wrap my head around the problem at hand. For example, if I were asked to solve the functional equation $$f(x+t) - f(x-t) = 4xt,$$ I simply wouldn't know where to start. With my experience in functions, I've learned to determine equations of inverses, the value of f(x) that emerges when one plugs in x values, and how to graph many types of functions, but these solutions of the more general type *really* get to my head. Any tips on how to approach a problem (and similar problems) like this? Many thanks.

Comment: Put $x=t$, and the solution drops out.

Comment: Thank you for the advice; however, how would one know to do this? Is it generally advisable to engender a cancellation of one of the two variables present in the equation to achieve a final solution?

Comment: Cancellation is nice! Often one does preliminary exploration, finding out the values of $f$ at nice numbers, and building up intuition. For example putting $x=0$ tells us $f(t)=f(-t)$, so our function is even. Although in this case the familiar identity $(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2=4xy$ jumps out, and we conjecture what the solution looks like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might represent this in a  nicer way by taking $u = x+t$, $v = x-t$, so $x = (u+v)/2$ and $t = (u-v)/2$, making the equation
$$ f(u) - f(v) = u^2 - v^2 $$
Next notice you can separate the $u$'s and the $v$'s.  What does that tell you?

Answer (score 6):

Put $x=t$ and the solution drops out.